# Can I create a symbolic link inside Azure file share for a file in Azure file share?

Tags: python, django, azure, sdk

I need some understanding and possibility on, how to create a `symbolic link` for a file present in Azure File share, inside another directory in the same file share.

Is it possible? If yes, then please provide an insight on how to do the same using the Azure Python SDK or Azure Portal.

PS: I looked into the `NTFSAttributes` class of Azure Python File share SDK. Is it possible to do it that way?

Any guidance on the above would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried using below code and I successfully uploaded symbolic link file name to my Azure file share from local machine.***

```py
from azure.storage.file import ContentSettings, FileService

file_service = FileService(account_name='strgaccount129', account_key='xxxxYour-storage-account-keykEbQyVIUtdxxxxxInRkzDF+AStPI60+Q==')

file_service.create_file_from_path(
    share_name='valleyfileshare129<file-share-name>',
    directory_name='data<fileshare-directoryname>',
    file_name='azcommands.txt<your-symboliklink-filename>',
    local_file_path=r'C:\Users\username\Documents\azcommands.txt',
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/x-symlink')
)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Hey Siddesh, thank you for the response. I would like add on a thing, I can see that you are using  Azure v2 Python SDK. Can you help me out with, which class would actually help me do the same in Azure v12 SDK. As my project is on the v12 version of the SDK, I'm not able to find out the `FileService` Class there.

Comment: Try this code - from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient, ShareDirectoryClient, ShareFileClient
from azure.storage.fileshare import ContentSettings

share_service_client = ShareServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="your_connection_string")
share_client = share_service_client.get_share_client(share_name="your_share_name")
directory_client = share_client.get_directory_client(directory_path="your_directory_path")
file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(file_path="your_file_path")

Comment: with open(local_file_path, "rb") as data:
    file_client.upload_file(data, length=file_size, overwrite=True, content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/x-symlink'))